# plsql Result consisted of more than one row. How to handel it

Tags: plsql

```
CREATE PROCEDURE book_check(book_Id varchar(64))
    begin 
    declare book_available varchar(64);

    select book_id into book_available 
    from book_copies 
    where No_of_Copies >0 and book_id=book_Id;

    if(book_Id in book_available ) then
        select concat ("Book available");
    else
        select concat ("Book not available");
    end if;
end
//
```

what can i write in place of 'in' . I know the syntax i wrong .

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: The plain [`select into`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/selectinto_statement.htm) is just for a single value. If you wanted to capture multiple values in one shot you'd need to define an array and use the [`bulk collect`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/tuning.htm#BABEIACI) clause. Obviously if you you want is an existence check you can do that without reading anything into memory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's unclear to me what you are trying to do. I *assume* you want to find out if a book is available or not and return that information to the caller of the function.

Your declaration of the procedure header and the variables is wrong.

- Procedure or function parameters are not defined with a length for the datatype.
- Inside a procedure or function you don't need `declare`
- you can't have a `select` statement without putting the result somewhere. * Assigning a constant value to a variable is done using `:=`
- If you want to return information to the caller, use a function, not a procedure
- You should not give variables or parameters the same name as a column. A common naming convention in the Oracle world is to give parameters the prefix `p_` and local variables the prefix `l_` but anything that avoids a name clash between column names and variables is OK - just be consistent.

```
CREATE function book_check(p_book_id varchar)
   return varchar
as
   l_count integer;
   l_result varchar(20);
begin 
  select count(*)
    into l_count
  from book_copies 
  where No_of_Copies > 0 
    and book_id = p_book_id;

  if l_count > 0 then 
    l_result := 'Book available';
  else
    l_result := "Book not available";
  end if;

  return result;

end;
/
```

You should really take the time and read the [PL/SQL Language reference](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/toc.htm). All the above is explained there.

Answer (score 1):

It's easy - try something like this:

```
create or replace function book_check(book_id varchar) return varchar as
begin 
    for r in (select 1 from book_copies where no_of_copies > 0 and book_id = book_check.book_id) loop
        return 'Book available';
    end loop;
    return 'Book not available';
end book_check;
/
```